# series function

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, exponentiation

We know that there are some series that can be written in short, for example:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x},\qquad |x|<1
$$
Is there similar function for
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N x^{1/n}
$$
or
$$
\sum_{n=2}^Nx^{1/n}
$$
in terms of $x$ and $N$
?

Comment: And if $x<0$, then $x^{1/n}$ doesn't exist if $n$ is even. (Or, if you're working in the complex numbers, $x^{1/n}$ approaches $-1$ for $n$ odd and $1$ for $n$ even.)

Comment: Ah, you just edited to the finite sum, I see.

Comment: I doubt a closed form formula exists.

Answer (score 4):

Since we are dealing with $x^{1/n}$, I assume that $x\gt0$. In that case, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x^{1/n}=1$, and thus the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{1/n}
$$
diverges by the [Term Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Comment: He edited it to become a finite sum.

Comment: Further, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( x^{1/n}-1 \right )$$ diverges.

Comment: @RonGordon: indeed, unless $x=1$, as the terms are $\frac{\log(x)}n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$x^{1/n}
=e^{\ln x/n}
=1+\frac{\ln x}{n}
+\frac{\ln^2 x}{2n^2}
+...
$,
$\sum_{n=1}^{M} \left(x^{1/n}-(1+\frac{\ln x}{n})\right)
=\sum_{n=1}^{M} x^{1/n}-M-H_M\ln x
$
converges,
so that could be considered
instead.